# QStyledItemDelegate with QComboBox: Shows Index and not Text

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QStyledItemDelegate` for a table. In one cell I have a `QComboBox` created through the delegate's `createEditor`. I add some items to the `combobox` listing via `self.addItem("an item");` however, when I go into the table and actually select the items I have added, they get replaced with index values starting from 0.

**How can I have the `QComboBox` display the actual text I added in `addItem` instead of the index they're getting stored in?**

Here is a small standalone example of my problem:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql

class EditDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(EditDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
            editor = TheEditor(parent)                  
            return editor

class TheEditor(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(TheEditor, self).__init__(parent)
            self.addItem("Item 1")
            self.addItem("Item 2")
            self.addItem("Item 3")
            self.setEditable(True)

class TheTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, columns, parent=None):
            super(TheTable, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setItemDelegate(EditDelegate())
            self.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
            self.setColumnCount(1)
            self.setRowCount(1)
            self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["QCombo"])

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setCentralWidget(TheTable(self))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Using `PyQt4` I always see `Item 1/2/3` as text both in the combo box and in the cell in the table. Can you provide an image of what you are seeing? (Edit: I just installed PySide and I get the same result as with PyQt4).

Comment: You're right, it turns out that it was some problem with the PySide version I was using: v1.1.2. I just upgraded to the latest v1.2.0 and this problem does not occur anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating PySide to the latest version resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the default combobox delegate is messing up with the data it receives.You could have fixed that with a custom delegate to paint the correct data. But since you have already solved it, Congratulations!.